# Shiro web filter chain order policy

Tags: shiro

Probably I'm in a kind of misunderstanding problem, but here is the thing:

- I want my `<domain>/index.html` publicly available and everything else should be protected.

I'm using shiro web + guice:

```
...

bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named("shiro.loginUrl")).to("/index.html");

addFilterChain("/index.html", ANON);
addFilterChain("/**", AUTHC);

...
```

This configuration is leading me to a "TOO MANY REDIRECTS LOOP" problem. Shiro documentation says [here](http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-URLPathExpressions) it uses a FIRST MATCH WIN policy, but I think I didn't get it well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the surface, your filter chain looks like it should work.  I probably can't diagnose your too many redirects issue without a bit more information - content of index.html, what http is actually returned from the server when you hit index.html, etc.

However, I CAN tell you that you shouldn't need to do this. The AUTHC filter has a special case for the "loginUrl" page - it will let it through.  So try removing the ANON filter, and see how things go.

Comment: Nice! Actually your answer gave the right clues and I figured out that my index.html (which hosts a GWT module) tries to reach a few GWT content not allowed according to my filter policy above. Now I need to make GWT requests secure with Shiro only after the module has been loaded. Thanks!!